# Android - Failed to find CMake

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I want to run [sensor-graph](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/sensor-graph) sample project

After the following:

1. Download Android Studio 2.2+ with NDK bundle.
2. Launch Android Studio.
3. Open android-ndk/sensor-graph sample.
4. Open File/Project Structure...
5. Click Download or Select NDK location.
6. Click Tools/Android/Sync Project with Gradle Files.
7. Click Run/Run 'app'.

i get follow error:

> Failed to find CMake.
>
> Gradle sync failed: Failed to find CMake.
>              Install from Android Studio under File/Settings/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK/SDK Tools/CMake.
>              Expected CMake executable at /Users/myUser/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/bin/cmake.
>              Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the Android NDK Bundle, you need to download CMake (and LLDB). Check in the SDK Manager to make sure you have these.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to SDK Manager -> SDK Tools tab, check CMake and click ok, Android Studio automatically download Cmake and Install it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Android NDK Bundle, you need to download CMake (and LLDB). Check in the SDK Manager to make sure you have these.

Go to SDK Manager -> SDK Tools tab, check CMake and click ok, Android Studio automatically download Cmake and Install it.